# Configuration.GetConnectionString returns null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to get a handle on how the Configuration manager is accessed throughout an demo project I'm working on. I deliberately NOT using Entity Framework Core, so I'm doing things more by hand, which means I need to access the configuration settings more explicitly than simply using the builder in the program file.

When I try and retrieve the connection string, it returns null.

Here is where I'm trying to prove out that I can see my connection string so that I can use it in my repositories eventually:

```
private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _logger = logger;
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    _configuration = configuration;
}

[HttpGet("getConfig")]
public string GetConfig() 
{
    var connString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    return connString;
}
```

And here is my `appsettings.json` file:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=library-mgmt-system; Trusted_Connection=true;"
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

When I call this method, it returns null. I'm using .NET Core 6.

Comment: Why do you have the _ConnectionStrings_ inside the _Logging_ key? It should be on its own

Answer (score 2):

I had the connection string in the logging key.